# Retain Row values without affecting other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that appears as follows:

|  | AOI | Year | Hectares |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Quneitra | 2015 | 11.46 |
| 2 | Quneitra | 2016 | 12.35 |
| 3 | Quneitra | 2017 | 14.65 |
| 4 | Hamah | 2015 | 1.8 |
| 5 | Hamah | 2016 | 2.7 |
| 6 | Hamah | 2017 | 3.5 |
| 9 | Tartus | 2015 | 12.2 |
| 10 | Tartus | 2016 | 12.7 |
| 11 | Tartus | 2017 | 14.2 |

How can I change this dataframe to remove the duplicate names of the AOI column without affecting the data on the adjacent columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.loc[df['AOI'].duplicated(), 'AOI'] = ''
```

but be aware that this should be done display only, this will otherwise prevent you to use your data for analysis!

As a temporary way (to avoid modifying the original DataFrame):

```
df2 = df.assign(AOI=df['AOI'].mask(df['AOI'].duplicated(), ''))
```

output:

```
         AOI  Year  Hectares
1   Quneitra  2015     11.46
2             2016     12.35
3             2017     14.65
4      Hamah  2015      1.80
5             2016      2.70
6             2017      3.50
9     Tartus  2015     12.20
10            2016     12.70
11            2017     14.20
```